# changing action bar title for every swipe api level < 11

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, swipe, swipe-gesture

I couldn't manage to change the action bar title for every swipe action, there's always a problem. Either they get mixed or just some of them does not show up. Here are my tab codes:

```
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    SectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    ViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    ViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    ViewPager
    .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });


    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setIcon(R.drawable.home)
            .setTabListener(this);
```

.
.
.
see answer below before going further into the question.

Comment: How are you keeping track of what String title should be ? And why is it static ?

Comment: @ToodeeJa-Py as I've said, "I set the title variable from every single fragment's OnStart() method." whenever a fragment's OnStart() triggers the String title is changed. That's also the reason why it's static, any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that onTabSelected is a method inside your fragment ?

Comment: @ToodeeJa-Py no no onTabSelected just receives the variable 'title' FROM the fragment classes that belong to my tabs. It doesn't properly work anyway, how can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using this in your Fragment's onResume method :

```
if(getUserVisibleHint()){
    getActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

defining String title as a variable inside your fragment.

Comment: We just thought alike I've tried using onResume but as I am about to discover, this is unmake-able. One has to chose between swiping or changeable action bar title. I've looked around and even google market uses it that way, I thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation on it: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging

and

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#swipe-tabs

Download the source code and use it. It worked for me. I had the same problem.